# program - UART communication for pic18f65k40

Tags: pic

I'm searching UART code for pic18f65k40, but i haven't found yet.
Could anyone please provide a sample code to transmit a single character using pic18f65k40 uart.

Answer (score 1):

This is the driver from my neolight theatre lighting controller. It is for a PIC18F14K22, but should be close enough to give you a start. This board also bit bangs the extremely fast protocol for the World Semi LEDs, hence the comment about timing.

```c
/* Neolight board optional UART support. The UART is used as an
   alternative to contact closures to trigger effects, and can be used
   to download completely arbitrary patterns to the LEDS.

   NOTE that during a write to the LEDs there are NO cycles left over
   to operate the UART, so it does not work during updates. The
   protocol reflects this.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include "neolight.h"

/* Baud rate calculation */

#define brgh 1    /* Use high rate mode */

#if brgh
#define divisor 4
#else
#define divisor 64
#endif

/* Macros to compute baud rate setup at compile time */
#define spbrg ( ( (long) Fosc ) / ( (long) divisor * (long) ( baud_rate ) ) - 1 )
#define spbrgl ( spbrg & 0xFF )
#define spbrgh ( ( spbrg >> 8 ) & 0xFF )

/* Turn on the UART and set baud rate */
void uart_setup ()
{
  RCSTAbits . SPEN = 1 ;
  BAUDCONbits . BRG16 = 1 ;
  TXSTAbits . TXEN = 1 ;
  TXSTAbits . BRGH = brgh ;
  RCSTAbits . CREN = 1 ;
  SPBRG = spbrgl ;
  SPBRGH = spbrgh ;
}

/* Send data to UART */
void uart_send ( unsigned char * buffer, int count )
{
  int n ;
  for ( n = 0; n < count; n++ )
    {
      while ( !TXSTAbits . TRMT ) ;
      TXREG = buffer [ n ] ;
    }
}

/* Receive from UART, return -1 if no char */
int uart_receive ()
{
  if ( RCSTAbits . OERR )
    {
      RCSTAbits . CREN = 0 ;
      RCSTAbits . CREN = 1 ;
    }

  if ( PIR1bits . RCIF )
    return RCREG ;
  else
    return -1 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Setup_UART(void)
{
    TX1STA    = 0b00100100;
    RC1STA    = 0b00010000;
    BAUDCON1  = 0b00001000;
    SP1BRGL   = xxx;           //Baudrate value, look at datasheet
    SP1BRGH   = xxx;
    RCSTA1bits.SPEN = 1;
}

void Send_Byte(uint8_t Data)
{
    while (!PIR3bits.TXIF);
    TX1REG = Data;
}
```

This example works for the PIC1827k40. Please have a look at the datasheet for your controller.

Comment: In all uart explanation i found that the data stream should contains start bit, parity and stop bits. But how to give start bits and stop bits in program and also they mentioned about clocks rising and falling edges. I don't know how to configure data in clock rising /falling edge in embedded c program.

Comment: start and stop bits are handled by the PIC which may be set in the specific UART register, similarly parity may be handled by the PIC (check registers that affect the data bits),as usually parity is not handled by the PIC for 7 data bits